# Arabic language not display proper in my home page

Tags: php, mysql, database, utf-8, arabic

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable";
$data = selectArray($sql);
```

> insert arabic data is = `تظهر البيانات العربي
>
> display in my database = ØªØ¸Ù‡Ø± Ø§Ù„Ø¨ÙŠØ§Ù†Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ
>
> display in cakePhp = تظهر البيانات العربية (display proper)
>
> display in corePhp = ØªØ¸Ù‡Ø± Ø§Ù„Ø¨ÙŠØ§Ù†Ø§Øª Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ

Let me know any one have solution of this issue.

Comment: @vnits Can you change database table field collation to 'utf8_general_ci' then check.

Comment: @ Lucky Saini- yes i know that and my created database query is : CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci; so i think there is any other issue. till i am not getting proper result.

Comment: In your text editor try to codificate in UTF-8 without BOM, i had the same problem with 'ñ'

Answer (score 0):

when create table use like this 
`CREATE DATABASE mydb DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;`

Comment: thank you for your response, still not any changes in result.

Comment: try this  echo html_entity_decode(stripslashes($yourtext), ENT_NOQUOTES))

Answer (score 0):

Mojibake -- search this forum for that.  You hit a common problem; this is a duplicate.